# How to solve SSL problem in internal rocket.chat server

Tags: ios, ssl, rocket.chat

I'm trying to create an internal Rocket.chat server.
It is ok to use on the browser (HTTP). But I want to use application to chat. So it must use SSL.

Following these [STEPS](https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309)
I can create a self-certificate (for the internal network only, not internet).
Https is running well now.

But, still 2 problem

1. When I put .cer file to ios, it is shown that **Not verified**
   (Unverified profile - The authenticity of "xxx" cannot be verified.) => So I can install it, but after installed, it is still not verified.
2. After install certificate, I go to rocket.chat App, and try to connect to my server (Connect to a server => https://myinternaldomain.com => it alert that SSL is not supported. Although I can run it on browser)

Anyone face to this problem? Please give me an advice.